# Clean URL of category page that uses pagination

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a site that has category pagination as follows

```
https://www.myweb.com/category.php?slug=commercial&page=1
```

and I would like to turn it into this

```
https://www.myweb.com/category/commercial/page/1
```

I currently have this in my .HTACCESS

```
RewriteRule  ^category/(.*)$/?$     category.php?slug=$1   [NC,L]
```

Which produces

```
https://www.myweb.com/category/commercial
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this rule for category pagination

```
RewriteRule  ^category/(.*)/page/(.*)$ category.php?slug=$1&page=$2   [NC,L]
```